# Atomic way of inserting a row if not exist in bigtable

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, hbase, bigtable

We would like to insert a row if not exist in bigtable. Our idea is to use `CheckAndMutateRow` api with a onNoMatch insert. We are using the nodejs sdk, the idea would be to do the following (it seems to works, but we don't no about the atomicity of the operation)

```
 const row = table.row('phone#4c410523#20190501');
  const filter = [];

  const config = {
    onNoMatch: [
      {
        method: 'insert',
        data: {
          stats_summary: {
            os_name: 'android',
            timestamp,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  await row.filter(filter, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CheckAndMutateRow` is atomic. Based on the [API definition](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/row.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row.ConditionalRow.commit):

> Mutations are applied atomically and in order, meaning that earlier mutations can be masked / negated by later ones. Cells already present in the row are left unchanged unless explicitly changed by a mutation.
> After committing the accumulated mutations, resets the local mutations.

Comment: What about performance? Is onNoMatch as performant as onMatch?

Answer (score 0):

MutateRow does an upsert. So if you give it a rowkey, column name and timestamp it will create a new cell if it doesn't exist, or overwrite it otherwise. You can achieve this behavior with a "simple write".

Conditional writes are use e.g. if you want to check the value before you overwrite it. Let's say you want to set column A to X only if column B is Y or overwrite column A only if column A's current value is Z.